# Unable to add behaviour to StateView in .Net Maui

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, maui

I had a Xamarin.forms app in which I am able to add. behaviour to a `StateView`. Now I am migrating the project into .Net Maui. After migrating the project I cant able to add the Behaviour to StateView anymore. It seems StateView became a static class in CommunityToolkit. How can I resolve this?

How I added the Behaviour to the `StateView`

```
static void OnAttachBehaviorChanged(BindableObject view, object oldValue, object newValue)
        {
            if (!(view is StateView stateView))
            {
                return;
            }

            bool attachBehavior = (bool)newValue;
            if (attachBehavior)
            {
                stateView.Behaviors.Add(new EntranceTransitionBehavior());
            }
            else
            {
                var toRemove = stateView.Behaviors.FirstOrDefault(b => b is EntranceTransitionBehavior);
                if (toRemove != null)
                {
                    stateView.Behaviors.Remove(toRemove);
                }
            }
        }
```

But Now in Maui, I am getting error like

> 'StateView' does not contain a definition for 'Behaviors' and no
> accessible extension method 'Behaviors' accepting a first argument of
> type 'StateView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?

Any help is appriciated.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, but is [StateContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/layouts/statecontainer) helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the MAUI, the StateView belongs to `StateContainer` and the type of StateView is `IList<View>` and it is the available View elements to be used as state templates.
It might be a little different from the Xamarin Community Toolkit StateLayout.

More information you can refer to the [.NET MAUI Community Toolkit StateContainer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/communitytoolkit/maui/layouts/statecontainer).

Comment: So I need to use StateContainer instead of Stateview?

Comment: You can check the [StateView.share.cs](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/blob/main/src/CommunityToolkit.Maui/Layouts/StateContainer/StateView.shared.cs). It has been defined as static.